# What is a Stuck Thread?

Tags: oracle, server, weblogic

The term **stuck thread** is commonly used in Oracle WebLogic Server.

- What is a stuck thread and why is thread diagnosed as a stuck thread?
- When does stuck thread occur?
- What kind of impact does it happen to
  the running application?
- What are the prevention mechanisms?

Comment: Your program becomes a Zombie and never dies.

Comment: So how can I know and catch this Zombie process?

Comment: Of course, but the how depends on what you are doing and with what tools... you know...

Answer (score 3):

Stuck Threads are threads that are blocked, and can't return to the threadpool for a certain amout of time. By Default, the WLS comes with 600 secs. If some thread doesn't return in 600 secs, It gets a flag 'stuck thread'.

– > Stuck Threads are only flags, there to warn you that this thread is taking too long.

Searching a bit on google I found this site: http://www.munzandmore.com/2012/ora/weblogic-stuck-threads-howto

It explains what are stuck threads, as well some methods to work around them.